# Extracts data using regular expression

Tags: python, regex, nlp

```
text='''

        Consumer Price Index:
        +0.3% in Aug 2020

        Unemployment Rate:
        +2.4% in Aug 2020
'''
```

extracts data into a list of tuples using regular expression, e.g.

```
[('Consumer Price Index', '+0.2%', 'Aug 2020'), ...]
```

and returns the list of tuples

I try several times by

```py
re.findall( , text)
```

Anyone have good ideas?

Comment: Is it just a big string?

Comment: Be very careful about specifying *what tool* to use to solve the problem when you post a question here. In this case regex is an ok tool to use but generally you're better off describing your problem in detail (sample input, sample desired output) and leaving the solution to the answer writers.

Comment: @ Oliver Hnat It's a short sample of text

Comment: What have you tried so far? Anything else than that single function call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first split the string by `'\n\n'` to segregate them into separate sections (to avoid confusion) then run a regex on each section to extract the groups.

See this as an example:

```
import re

text = '''

        Consumer Price Index:
        +0.2% in Sep 2020

        Unemployment Rate:
        +7.9% in Sep 2020
        '''


sections = text.split('\n\n')

results = []

for section in sections:
    pattern = re.compile(r'\s+([\w\s]+):\n.+(\+.+) in ([\w\d\s]+)')

    matches = pattern.match(section)

    if matches:
        results.append(matches.groups())

print(results)
```

**output:**

```
[
   ('Consumer Price Index', '+0.2%', 'Sep 2020'),
   ('Unemployment Rate', '+7.9%', 'Sep 2020')
]
```

---

**update:**

Here is a solution with `re.findall` but like I said there might be inconsistencies depending on how `text` is structured. You should divide-and-conquer just to be on the safe side.

```
import re

text = '''

        Consumer Price Index:
        +0.2% in Sep 2020

        Unemployment Rate:
        +7.9% in Sep 2020
        '''


sections = text.split('\n\n')

pattern = re.compile(r'\s+([\w\s]+):\n.+(\+.+) in ([\w\d\s]+)\n')

results = pattern.findall(text)

print(results)
```

Comment: What about re.findall